# Get pointer from vector's element

Tags: c++

I want to get a pointer from vector's element which has `Fd` property set on desired value. Right now I am using this ugly code:

```
User* Game::GetUser(int fd)
{
    for(auto& v : users)
        if (v.Fd == fd)
            return &v;

    return nullptr;
}
```

How can I change this code to be more similar to this:

```
void Game::RemoveUser(int fd)
{
    users.erase(remove_if(begin(users), end(users), [fd](User const& u)
    {
        return u.Fd == fd;
    }), end(users));
}
```

Or maybe there are other, much better ways to code this?

Comment: Why do you think it's "ugly"? Would you rather have e.g. `std::find_if(begin(users), end(users), [fd](auto const& v){ return v.Fd == fd; })` and then check that it didn't return `end(users)` before deciding what to return?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think it can be considered ugly as the same logic expressed in 2 different ways. Maybe ugly is not right term, but it is definitely more error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change this code to be more similar to this

Just use `std::find_if` with the same predicate:

```
User* Game::GetUser(int fd)
{
    auto it = find_if(begin(users), end(users), [fd](User const& u)
    {
        return u.Fd == fd;
    }));
    return it == end(users) ? nullptr : &*it;
}
```

to avoid code duplication you can use result of `find_if` for erase as well:

```
  users_type::iterator findUser( int fd)
  {
        return find_if(begin(users), end(users), [fd](User const& u)
        {
             return u.Fd == fd;
        }));
  }

User* Game::GetUser(int fd)
{
     auto it = findUser( fd );
     return it == end( users ) ? nullptr : &*it;
 }

void Game::RemoveUser(int fd)
{
     auto it = findUser( fd );
     if( it != end(users) )
         users.erase( it );
}
```

you may consider to use different container if such operations has to happen quite often, as both `std::find_if` and `std::remove_if` are linear to number of elements. Or you may want to keep `users` sorted and use `std::equal_range()` instead of `std::find_if()` which is `log(N)`, but you would need to use `findUser` to find proper location to insert or use `std::sort` after insertion(s).